# Using Swift Mailer AntiFlood Plugin or Throttler Plugin with Symfony 1.3

Tags: php, symfony1

What is the syntax for the using Swift Mailer Plugins in Symfony 1.3?

Its not:

```
$email = $this->getMailer()->compose();
$email->setSubject($subject);
$email->setFrom($from);
$email->setTo($to);
$email->setBody($body, 'text/html');
$email->addPart($plain, 'text/plain');
$email->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));
$email->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin(100, Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin::MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try:

```
$this->getMailer()->getRealtimeTransport()->registerPlugin($pluginInstance);
```

OR:

```
$this->getMailer()->registerPlugin($pluginInstance);
```